# how to pass picture height and width to an html lightbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, variables

I am using a bootstrap lightbox implementation in my website. For the lightbox to work best,  I need to provide the actual height and width of each picture displayed in the lightbox.  I'm looking for a way to do provide this data dynamically instead of having to code each picture.  I know you can obtain the data using javascript, but I know you can't use a variable in HTML.  Is there some work around for this, perhaps using CSS variables?

For example (obviously this won't work) how can I pass this data-size?

```
<body>
  <figure class="col-md-4">
    <a href="p1.jpg" data-size=var(imgSize)>
      <img src="p1.jpg" class="img-fluid">
    </a>
  </figure>   
  <script>
    var img = new Image();
    var imgSize = this.width + 'x' + this.height;
    img.src = 'p1.jpg';
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

try wrapping your dynamic data in a function and calling it in your attribute

```
    <body>
  <figure class="col-md-4">
    <a href="p1.jpg" data-size=imgSize()>
      <img src="p1.jpg" class="img-fluid">
    </a>
  </figure>   
  <script>
    var img = new Image();
    var imgSize = functions() { this.width + 'x' + this.height};
    img.src = 'p1.jpg';
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't think you can call a function outside of a <script> tag?

Answer (score 0):

according to this [documentation](https://ashleydw.github.io/lightbox/) what you must try to obtain is :

```
data-(width|height)="[0-9]+"
```

Here is how to edit an attribut in Jquery :

```
    $('tag').attr('data-width', valuex);
    $('tag').attr('data-height', valuey);
```

And this way you can get image size :

```
var img = $('#imgid')
var width = img.width();
var height = img.height();
```